# Android Error IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make custom lock screen. So, there I need not to allow user to press *Home Button*. In the begining I write

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lock_screen);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

Then I override *OnKeyDown*

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)||(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)||(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)||(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)) {
        //this is where I can do my stuff
        return true; //because I handled the event
    }
    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)){

        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Here I override *onAttacheToWindow*

```
 @Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

But it's giving me error **IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.** Where is my mistake?

**How can I handle Home Button?**

Comment: **Window type can not be changed after the window is added** and you do this by calling `this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);` in `onAttachedToWindow()` method

Comment: @hema18 How can I handle Home Button?

Comment: You can not handle home button but you can override `onStop()` method [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10869900/3512164)