# IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added

Tags: android, android-activity, android-windowmanager

I've tried the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072866/toddler-safe-app-on-android), the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594412/android-error-illegalargumentexception-window-type-can-not-be-changed-after-the), the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568078/android-error-illegalargumentexception-window-type-can-not-be-changed-after), I've commented out the onAttachedToWindow() in my Base Activity.  I have two Activities inheriting from this class, BaseActivity.  One runs, and one does not. What could be the difference?  My target SDK is 19; changing it to 12 makes no difference.  Here is my onCreate for BaseActivity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ....
    }
```

When navigating to the second activity, stepping through the code, it makes it through onCreate(), onResume(), then crashes.

What could be the problem?

Stacktrace:

```
06-26 13:41:57.963  28667-28667/com.assistek.ediary E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.assistek.ediary, PID: 28667
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1550)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
        at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout(IWindowSession.java:903)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:5301)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1507)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**EDIT**: if I change to target API 12 and put all of the changes in from `onCreate` into `onAttachedToWindow`, I can get this exception to go away, but I'd like the target SDK to be 19.

My **new** onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
}
```

My **new** onAttachedToWindow():

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

This only works with target API 12.

**Answer**
[Min target must be less than 14 when WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34300546/min-target-must-be-less-than-14-when-windowmanager-layoutparams-type-keyguard-us?lq=1)

Comment: try this for API 19 : https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: Do not call `super.onAttachedToWindow()` anywhere other than from inside your override of `onAttachedToWindow()`, if you have one. While I cannot speak to `TYPE_KEYGUARD`, the rest of that code should be after `super.onCreate()`, but before any `setContentView()` call. Beyond that, see if you have anything interesting in your manifest that might explain the difference between your two activities.

Comment: The only thing that's different between the two activities is: android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"

Comment: I did also move everything back to onAttachedToWindow.

Comment: someone mentioned allready taht the super.onCretae() should be called at the beginning of onCreate(), so try this. And also you dont need to call the onAttachedWindow() method!

Answer (score 7):

Try to use this for window :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_adjectives);
```

Comment: This will probably be the answer that gets awarded the bounty, but this answer DID NOT WORK.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same question. But after stopping adding

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` of `BaseActivity`, it works well. I cut and paste above codes before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` of descends of `BaseActivity`.

BTW, I don't think you have to call `super.onAttachedToWindow();` inside methods of life circle of `Activity`. Because `onAttachedToWindow();` is called when the view is attached to a window when you overriding a `View`.

Comment: getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD); TYPE_KEYGUARD is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, but I solved it by removing the Window, changing the params and then adding the window again. This was good enough for me.

`WindowManager.removeView(View);
params = params2; //changed the params to something else
WindowManager.updateViewLayout(View, params);
WindowManager.addView(View, params);`

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me in an AccessibilityService overlay. But the `updateViewLayout` isn't necessary since the view has already been removed from the window and will be re-added in the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

From your `onAttachedToWindow()`, like this:

```
 @Override
     public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        //this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

          super.onAttachedToWindow();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply. You should add:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

in **onCreate** method if you are using api level 15 or above. It works for me.