# Catching when the user pressed the Home Button

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

I would like to know when the user pressed the home button while he was running my app.
BUT:
The problem is that I don't want to edite the existing code.
meaning I don't want to add logic to the existing activities `onPause()` method.

The only solution I found was to add a service to the application which listens to the Log detecting if there was an intent to run the

> HOME: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.HOME]

Is there any other way to do it or is it really impossible?
The optimal solution would have been to catch an intent in the *Manifest.xml*, like:

> action android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"

and implement a new class to catch it. (But it doesn't seem to catch it).

Comment: A duplicate of this question is available here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101346/android-how-to-catch-that-the-home-button-was-pressed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881951/detect-home-button-press-in-android/55129289#55129289

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know when the user pressed the home button while he was running my app.

What specifically are you trying to achieve?

> BUT: The problem is that I don't want to edite the existing code.

By definition, that is impossible.

> The only solution I found was to add a service to the application which listens to the Log detecting if there was an intent to run the

That is modifying the code, violating your own requirement. Moreover, it requires a permission that really you should not be asking for.

> Is there any other way to do it or is it really impossible?

That depends on what specifically you are trying to achieve.

> The optimal solution would have been to catch an intent in the Manifest.xml...and implement a new class to catch it. (But it doesn't seem to catch it).

`HOME` is a category. It is not an action. Home screens are activities that respond to the `MAIN` action in the `HOME` category. However, it is modifying the code, violating your own requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use key press event handler

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
            // Home key pressed
        } else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The HOME button is not sent to `onKeyDown()`.