# How to catch HOME action in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - How to catch that the Home button was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101346/android-how-to-catch-that-the-home-button-was-pressed)

Is there a way to stop going to the main screen when the HOME key is pressed?

Basically, I want to restrict the user to go out to the home screen when using my app, so I should restrict the HOME and BACK keys.

Comment: Overriding the home and back key isn't generally approved and in most cases bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement your own home screen. If the user elects to make your app be their home screen, you get control when the user presses HOME. You can see an example home screen application in the SDK samples, available for download from the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

[Intercept HOME key in Android](http://nisha113a5.blogspot.in/2012/01/intercept-home-key-android.html)

Comment: That technique does not work on modern versions of Android.